# MySQL триггер insert, который перед добавлением обновляет поле другой записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Можно ли триггером на добавление обновить поле другой записи, которая имеет те же значения в 2 столбцах?
Например имеется запись

```
id   id_product  id_shop  price   status_sales
1       2          3      10000         1
```

Мы ходим добавить запись

```
2       2          3      12000         1
```

Триггер должен изменить значение status sales = 0 записи, у которой равны id_product и id_shop добавляемой записи

Пытаюсь сделать так, но выходит ошибка

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_add` BEFORE INSERT  ON `price` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE price
SET price.status_sales = 0
WHERE price.product_variantion_id = new.product_variantion and price.shop_id = new.shop_id and price.status_sales = 1
END
```

Ошибка

```
#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'END' на строке 6
```

Comment: можно конечно. поля изменяемой таблицы доступны в виде NEW.имя_поля, вы можете использовать их в условиях в предложении update

Comment: @Mike добавил код моего недоделанного триггера, в чем ошибка?

Comment: после предложения update нужна точка с запятой (т.е. прямо перед END). А перед созданием триггера стоит поменять разделитель предложений с помощью `DELIMITER //` и после END добавить эти `//`. Но вообще это зависит от вашей программы из которой вы создаете триггер, у нее могут быть свои требования по поводу изменения разделителей запросов (или не быть таковых вообще и она сама все поймет)

Comment: @Mike спасибо, триггер создался, только я теперь не могу добавить какую либо запись, выдает: #1442 - Can't update table 'price' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: Я сразу не заметил, что вы пытаетесь менять ту же таблицу на которую триггер. К сожалению, это не возможно. Или меняйте другие записи вне триггера после вставки новой записи. Или вообще не храните поле status_sales и вычисляйте его при выборке из таблицы, когда оно нужно

Comment: @Mike можете тогда посоветовать как сделать? Я хотел чтобы этот параметр указывал на актуальность данных, 1 актуальные, 0 - история. Нужно именно ввести архив записей, чтобы я мог выбирать определенные записи, и чтобы выбирались только актуальные данные. Думаю можно создать вспомогательную таблицу, куда будут перемещаться записи из этой триггером при добавлении новой записи. Может вы посоветуете что-то другое?

Comment: Смотря как часто и для чего нужна история. Варианты: Пользуемся одной таблицей, то у цен есть дата начала и окончания действия. Если цена активна сейчас дата окончания 01.01.3000 например. Но триггером ее не выправить. изменяющий скрипт перед вставкой записи закрывает предыдущую. Вариант 2: в основной таблице только текущие данные, в нее соответственно всегда дается insert on dupblicate key update. триггер перед обновлением записи переносит старые данные в арзивную таблицу

Comment: @Mike а как вам такой вариант? перед вставкой данных, у всех записей этого магазина обновляем параметр, например на status_sale = 0, что указывает, что цена запись не актуальна. Вставляем записи с параметров 1. А для истории выбираем с параметром 0?

Comment: Можно и так. только я бы все таки делал даты, а не признак. вот ушли у вас две записи по одному продукту в магазине в архив, а вы даже не знаете какая была раньше, а какая позже. Опять же если надо выдавать какие нибудь выходные формы за прошлые периоды, можно всегда использовать цены на нужную дату. Строить аналитику по изменению цены во времени. Хотя это конечно вам решать исходя из вашей задачи, достаточно ли просто признака

Comment: @Mike такой признак есть, я его просто здесь не показал, поле со значением по умолчанию CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Только мне его формат Y-m-d h:m:s не нравится. Как его можно изменить или придется самому значение времени добавлять

Comment: формат вывода можно явно задавать например с помощью date_format http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html